# Why is the +number in the physics SE users list different from the +number in my profile (on a yearly basis)?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation change on the user list on the Physics SE site this year is about +1500, as can be seen. But according to my profile on that site which can also be seen, my reputation change is only around +500. Some screenshots of these indicators:

The Users list:

> [image]

My profile:

> [image]

As one can see the difference is $1550-566=984$! So, again: How can that be?

Comment: I'm not sure that you're suggesting it, but note that since your rep is above 2k, you don't get the +2 rep bump for editing posts.

Comment: What does this have to do with my question? I don't care that much about reputation, as you (all?) seem to think (though it **does** make things really nicer to make a kind of competition of it). I mean what are **2** points in that perspective. I 've got -6 for this question. Do you think I care? Absolutely not!! I asked for something completely different but that's another question which can't be asked here obiously.

Comment: You said, "I haven't got any reactions...while I made a bunch of edited questions and answers" which sort of sounds like you were expecting a rep change for that.

Comment: The [first screenshot in your edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrloD.jpg) shows the reputation change for this **month**, not this year. How is this relevant to the question, which asks for the yearly change?

Comment: The +568 in the second screenshot does not show the yearly reputation either. Why would you assume that it does so? There is a [fully-informative tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FkqA.png) available, accessible by hovering your mouse on top of that box (same as *all* the other informational tooltips on SE) that explains the number clearly - it is the reputation gain since the last time you visited the Reputation tab on your profile.

Comment: I've already edited it because I see exactly what you mean! So the 1000 hours were well spent!!!

Comment: Oh yeah! I have to take screenshots of both years. Let me pause for a moment.

Comment: To be frank: this question feels extremely disingenuous, particularly when coupled with your aggressive reactions further up on this comment thread. I'm having an extremely hard time understanding how a question phrased in this way, and with such huge gaps in seeing obvious features, could arise in good faith, instead of being a simple attempt at trolling this community. Please take that onboard and, if this is indeed a good-faith question, take appropriate steps in doing your due diligence before posting or editing.

Comment: Why the hell did you edit? I told you I was editing. I have it all right now and now I can't submit it anymore!!!

Comment: Can't you delete your edit? I've made some substantial edits that make it finally clear and also answers my question?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sorry for all the misunderstanding and all the prejudging!! You did a good job indeed. I was just confused because it's the first time I looked at a users list. And it was even accidentally!! It only goes to show...

Comment: I edited because over 60% of the text in the post was irrelevant to the discussion and should never have been introduced. (It goes without saying that I'm not going to roll back that edit.) Language of the form "why the hell did you edit" is *absolutely* not appropriate here -- if you post posts that need improvement and you do not fix them, then [other people can and will edit them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/editing); that's how this platform works, period. Replying with harassment is in no way appropriate, and it does little to build an impression of good faith.

Comment: Are you asking about the blue number beside the reputation tab?

Comment: As for your current edit (v11), the title does not match the body, and the edit is so substantial that it makes the existing (accepted!) answer not match the question (which, as I imagine you're already well aware, is a big no-no here).

Comment: You're absolutely right! So, again, my apologies. It **is** indeed the way it works here. But maybe you can have a bit, just a little bit because I'm feeling so impulsive right now. Which can mean that I can make the other people impress that I'm aggressive. I feel very good, after many years of *not** feeling too good, even very bad. I know the reason for that now, so my body and brain kicked it out. Which gave this good, but indeed quite aggressive (not really meant, but indeed said) I won't behave in this kind of manner anymore.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Now I understand why my next badge on this site is the one for peer (which in Dutch means pear) pressure...:)

Comment: Wow, you have over 8k rep but only voted on 400 posts and (successfully) raised one flag?!

Comment: Thanks. So, are we "friends" again?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I did some heavy editing (so I did take an effort to make it understandable), while one of the two (@knzhou) questions got a +1 of mine and was accepted by me. The other answer (@John Rennie) wasn't useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number on the reputation tab on your profile is the amount of reputation you've gained since the last time you personally clicked on that tab. That fits the pattern with numbers on all of the other tabs.

Comment: Alright. So it **Isn't** the number +es I've in the **whole** year?

Comment: But why it is to read in the meta site of mine I have a reputation of +8329? It suggests that on that site I have such that reputation, which in fact is about ?? below zero? I'm in at this kind of thing.  But I think that's about the connection between both sides.

Comment: Don't you think it's like I said in the "other" question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your rep change this year is 1,523 rather than 539:

[image: Rep change]

And that puts you on page four on the list of all users:

[image: All users]

Comment: Right now, I've just looked at, it's +555. So why is 1000 added to it?

Comment: And right now I'm not in it anymore at all!! Very confusing. Or does it take some time?

Comment: @John Rennie I mean the difference between the + on the users list and what my profile says.

Comment: It's already clear. I suddenly realized my reputation was almost doubled because of a change in policy: both questions, as well as answers, get 10 points awarded when upvoted.